# I need help installing emacs and the avr things on windows so i can use arduino uno

Tags: windows, emacs, arduino, avr

So I did some Arduino programing on emacs on a university machine that had Linux. I want to use my windows computer to play around the same code. The problem is that I installed emacs for windows, the make file thing, avrdude,avr8-gnu-toolchain-win32_x86,gnuwin32 and I put all the different PATHs and stuff, and I still get errors on something that worked on the university Linux machine so the problem shouldn't be the code. When I type "compile" and then "make -k lst upload" as I did in the Linux machine it gives me this error:

```
"make -k lst upload
make: Nothing to be done for `lst'.
avrdude -p m328p -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -Uflash:w:traffic_light.hex
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": The system cannot find the path specified.
avrdude done.  Thank you.
make: *** [upload] Error 1
```

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Nov 18 15:25:40"
I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Sebas

Comment: Hi Sebas, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think your question is off-topic here, and you should ask on Super User instead. Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: At least the `arduino` tag is not applicable, because _Arduino_ means not to care about makefiles etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AVRDUDE is trying to open `/dev/ttyACM0`, which is a Linux-style name of a USB virtual serial port.  That name does not exist on Windows.  Instead, you have to use a name like "COM6".  You can look in the Device Manager and expand the "Ports (COM & LPT)" list to see what ports are available.  If a port is not available, you will need to install the proper USB drivers for your device.

By the way, you could consider using MSYS2 to install AVRDUDE, Make, and everything else you need except the avr-gcc toolchain.  But that is not a solution to your current problem, which is that you are specifying the wrong serial port.

Comment: How can i change the port that avrdude is using?

Comment: Edit your Makefile with a text editor.  Find `/dev/ttyACM1` and replace it with something like `COM6`, depending on your machine's setup.